# login code in cakephp 2.7 using auth component

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.7.8

Tablename - **users**

**fields in table**

id
name
email
password

i am trying to login and if login is succesful then it redirects to ad page.

but i dont now why

**My login shows error after form submit**

**Invalid username and password.**

but my table contain the exact value available.

plz help me find out error.

controller file name -  UsersController.php

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {   

      public $helpers = array('Form', 'Html');
      public $components = array('Flash');

     public function beforeFilter() 
     {
        parent::beforeFilter();     
        $this->Auth->allow('add');
     }

     public function login() {
       if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                //print_r($this->request->is('post'));
                //exit;
                if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add')));
                }
                $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Model file name - User.php

```
<?php

class User extends AppModel {

public $validate = array('lname' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'));

}
?>
```

login.ctp

```
<?php 
echo $this->form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
echo $this->form->input('email');
echo $this->form->input('password');
echo $this->form->end('login');
?>
```

**Appcontroller.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

     public $components = array(
        'Flash',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            )
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view','update','delete');
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcakephp%5D+auth+email+instead+of+username**

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to declare this line

```
     public $components = array('Flash'); // in UsersController.php
```

Because you've already declared the components array in the AppController itself.  ->>

```
   public $components = array(
    'Flash',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        )
    )
);
```

Also, you could modify this login part a bit.

```
   if ($this->Auth->login()) {
       return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index'));

         or 

        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
  }
```

It sometimes causes a problem with the Session and the redirect Url. Write a code for logout and try logging back in again. It works sometimes.

Also, try debugging and write:

```
   pr($this->Auth->user()); in your login action in UsersController.
```

In case the user is logged in, it will return an array of the logged in user's data.

Peace! xD